# Store "Coins" in Android/iOS app that cannot be hacked

Tags: android, ios, security, encryption

I haven't been able to find exactly what I've been looking for by searching the web. Basically, I am making an app with digital currency that I don't want users to be able to hack and add coins to their account. I was thinking of 2 methods to do this, I want to know your opinions on them and how you would approach them to be as secure as possible. I'm not too sure about them but here they are:

1. Store the data on the user's device with an encryption. The issue with this is that if the user has root access, they could potentially decrypt it.
2. Give each phone a UUID and store their "coin" information in a database. Every time they open the app, they are automatically logged in using the UUID. This prevents the need to create passwords and usernames. The issue with this is that someone could decrypt the UUID off someone else's device and use it on their own to steal it. Also this would make the experience potentially slower and would cost more for me to do.

So what is the best solution? Do you know of any other ways? Thanks in advance.

Extra info: I plan on using LibGDX since it is cross platform and may be a good place to start but it may also limit what I can do. I am willing to use native android and eventually do the same on iOS if it allows for a much more secure experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot store data locally 100% secure**. As soon as your app itself can read/write the local coin count the "attacker" can as well.

The only secure option is to save it on a server. Of course every increase / decrease of the coin count has to happen on the server itself and be checked for validity before saved.

Note: You cannot *"decrypt the UUID off someone else's device"* as long as the server is secure.

Comment: So android has its own UUID that I can use?

Comment: @vedi0boy Yes, either you create some device/application-specific one that is the same for every launch on the same device or you just create a general random UUID that you have to manually save and load.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. So the only way to hack into someone else's account would be to physically have their phone to decrypt the uuid, that's what I was talking about, not through the server. I guess the chances of that are extremely unlikely so it should be good. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @vedi0boy Yes, if you get access to another users phone, you of course can gets its id. But if someone gets access to your phone getting some id of some app is by far not the biggest problem you have ;) And that is nothing you as a developer really have to worry about - that is the users fault and nothing you can do to change or prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

1. UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers) are unique across space and time. They just are, there is nothing to decrypt.
2. The problem of digital currencies has been solved: Bitcoin, Litecoin and the spin offs. It is not an easy of trivial thing to create. If you are dealing with "coins" that have any real value you really need to get your scheme and security vetted by a digital security domain expert, expect to pay several thousand dollars.
3. Root access does not protect the encrypted data, the data can only be decrypted with the correct key, generally 128 to 256 bits of random data. The protection problem moves to protecting the key. About the best you can do is create a random key to use and save it in the keychain (iOS, Android keychain has more restrictive usage). But if the device does not have a good passcode (or any or good) there is little to no security. In general protecting data from the valid user is difficult and usually falls under DRM, needs servers and authentication.
4. LibGDX: the more obscure coding system you use the less help is available, think carefully about that. Also if you have competition the UI is very important. While it is generally said that you only have one chance to impress the user you have multiple opportunities to make them unhappy/angry ex-users. Cross platform systems tend to have poorer UI and more non-standard from the native UI on each platform.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll look into making native apps on iOS, just really sucks that you need a mac.

Comment: Sucks not using a Mac. But for Masochist the development can be done without a Mac. For a Mac just get a cheap MacMini with 8GB or more RAM on eBay.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.